# passing real arrays from fortran 90 to fortran 77

Tags: fortran, double, fortran90, fortran77

I have a third-part code in fortran 77, and I have written a subroutine in fortran 90 that I would like to interface to this code. I have found that the variables are not passed correctly from one subroutine to the other. I think the reason is that the definitions of double precision in the two programs is not compatible.

I want that the variable returned to f77 is a `double precision`. Which real definition shall I use in f90? I am using `selected_real_kind(p=15,r=307)`

---

EDIT: 
I have changed the declaration to `double precision` in f90, and I have verified that `double precision` variables are passed correctly. The problem arises when I am passing allocatable arrays from f90 to f77

The arrays are originally allocated in code f77. then I allocate some allocatable arrays in f90 and then pass them to f77, but this is not working

f77 code:

```
    program oldprog
    double precision da(100)

    call sub(da)
    end

    subroutine sub(da)
    double precision da(*)
    call mynewsub(da)
    end
```

f90 code:

```
subroutine mynewsub(da)
  implicit none
  double precision, allocatable:: da(:)
  allocate(da(100))
  da = 1.0
end subroutine mynewsub
```

I was thinking to skip the allocation in mynewsub, but then I get SIGSEGV

Comment: asuming you dont want to modify the old code, just use `double precision` in the new code so you know its consistant. (you can of course update the old code to use `selected_real_kind` as well)

Comment: Check what the two compilers in question use for `double precision` but it is likely that, in both cases, it is IEEE 754 64 bit binary.

Comment: I have tried using `double precision`, but the variables are not passed correctly, maybe because I am passing allocatable array?

Comment: *"The arrays are originally allocated in code f77"* This is some nonsence there are **no** allocatble arrays in FORTRAN 77. Show your code.

Comment: well are allocated as static arrays in f77, then I allocate allocatable arrays in f90 and pass them back

Comment: If you always want `da` to be 100, then you don't need it to be allocatable. Why not remove the `allocate` statement and the `allocatable` attribute?

Comment: If the purpose is just to pass an array in the F77 code to an assumed-shape dummy argument, we need an explicit interface (e.g., module or interface block), but is it given? http://www.cs.rpi.edu/~szymansk/OOF90/bugs.html#8 (Also, please try modifying `da(*)` to `da(100)` to simplify matters.).

Comment: you can of course use an assumed *size* declaration same as in the old code `double precision da(*)`

Comment: i guess i should have finished, you can *pass* as assumed size, but you wont be able to use any modern fortran features that  require knowledge of the array size (such as the array assignment in the example).

Comment: If the dummy argument is explicit-shape or assumed-size, you can of course pass assumed-size actual arrays (it simply passes the address of the first element). But if the dummy is assumed-shape, gfortran and ifort complains... But anyway, I feel the question itself is very vague, so still don't know what the intent of the OP XD

Answer (score 1):

Your `mynewsub` accepts the array as allocatable argument.

That requires explicit interface in Fortran 95, and is impossible in Fortran 90, not even speaking about FORTRAN 77 which does not have `allocatable` at all.

You cannot do this.

And in your main program

```
program oldprog
    double precision da(100)
```

the array is static. It cannot be reallocated in any way in any version of Fortran, it is fixed forever.

You should think about making it allocatable everywhere an update relevant parts of your code to Fortran 95.

Comment: I don't want to modify the f77 code. can I rewrite the f90 subroutine with the assumed-shape, as described in http://www.fortran90.org/src/best-practices.html ? If I remove `allocate` in`mynewsub`, fortran thinks `da` is not allocated and segmentation fault

Comment: Usually I find when I remove ALLOCATE that I should also remove mentions of ALLOCATABLE